# How to set the objects in the GridView fill the whole height?

Tags: windows, xaml, gridview, win-universal-app

How to set the items in the GridView fill the whole height?
I would like to GridView always have 4 rows. Currently I set that images have a height of 120.

My code:

```
            <GridView
                Grid.Row="1" 
                x:Name="gridView" 
                SelectionChanged="gridView_SelectionChanged"
                ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                SelectionMode="None"
                IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                ItemClick="gridView_ItemClick">
                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Background="Black">
                            <Image x:Name="ima" Height="120" Stretch="UniformToFill">
                                <Image.Source>
                                    <BitmapImage x:Name="bm" UriSource="{Binding Pa}"  ImageOpened="bm_ImageOpened"/>
                                </Image.Source>
                            </Image>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" VerticalChildrenAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemsPanel>
            </GridView>
```

Comment: Did you tried `<BitmapImage VerticalAlingment="Streched" ...` ?

Comment: "The property VerticalAlingment was not found in type 'BitmapImage' '. If I put the VerticalAlingment in the Image then it does not do anything. There are still large spaces between items.

Comment: What is the problem? How to make 4 rows, or spacing between pictures?

Comment: I would like the images have a maximum height such that the gridview always have 4 rows regardless of screen resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a converter class that divides the Window height by an input parameter:

```
class DivisionConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string culture)
    {
        double windowHeight = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
        double divideBy = Double.Parse(parameter as string);
        return windowHeight / divideBy;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Make the converter available within XAML:

```
<Page .... >
    <Page.Resources>
        <local:DivisionConverter x:Key="DivisionConverter"/>
    </Page.Resources>
```

Then use the converter with data binding:

```
<Image
    x:Name="ima"
    Height="{Binding Converter={StaticResource DivisionConverter}, ConverterParameter=5}"
    Stretch="UniformToFill">
```

Notice that I am dividing by 5, since there are always margins and paddings around the items that will prevent you from fitting 5 rows: `Image.Height * 5 + margins > Grid.Height`.